# ansible not running handlers from included roles

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run notify on a handler in the same role and that role is being included as a dependency.

Here's my playbook

```
root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat monitor.yml
---

- hosts: local
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - common
    - role: sensu
      sensu_install_server: true
```

My common files look like

```
root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat roles/common/tasks/main.yml
- name: Add the OS specific variables
  include_vars: '{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml'

#
# ansible run script
- name: copy the ansible-run script
  copy:
    src=ansible-run.py
    dest=/usr/bin/ansible-run
    owner=root
    group=root
    mode=0700
- cron: name="cron ansible-run" minute="*/5" job="/usr/bin/ansible-run > /dev/null 2&1"


#
# ntp
- name: Install ntp
  package: name=ntp state=present
- name: Start/stop ntp service
  service: name={{ ntp_service_name }} state=started enabled=yes



root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat roles/common/meta/main.yml
---
dependencies:
  - { role: users }
  - { role: sensu }
```

My sensu role is where I want the notify to work in the `tasks/client.yml`

```
root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat roles/sensu/tasks/main.yml

- include: common.yml

- include: server.yml
  when: sensu_install_server
  ignore_errors: true

- include: client.yml





root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat roles/sensu/tasks/client.yml
- name: reload ansible_local
  setup: filter=ansible_local

- name: copy plugins files
  copy:
    src=files/sensu/plugins/
    dest=/etc/sensu/plugins/
    owner=sensu
    group=sensu
    mode=0750
  notify:
    - restart sensu client


- name: generate config files
  template:
    src=client.json.j2
    dest=/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json
    owner=sensu
    group=sensu
    mode=0640
    backup=yes
  notify:
    - restart sensu client

- name: enable sensu-client to survive reboot
  service:
    name=sensu-client
    enabled=yes
    state=started



root@monitor:/etc/ansible# cat roles/sensu/handlers/main.yml
---
# handlers file for sensu
- name: restart sensu server
  service: name=sensu-{{ item }} state=restarted
  with_items:
    - server
    - api

- name: restart sensu client
  service: name=sensu-client state=restarted

- name: restart uchiwa service
  service: name=uchiwa state=restarted

- name: restart nginx service
  service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

A look from a run shows the client.json gets changed but I never see a notify for the handler being called.

Comment: Is it a typo or configuration mistake: `roles/sensu/handlers/main.html`? Look at the end. It should be `.../main.yml`.

Comment: @bangal yes that was a test to see if I got an error if there was no yaml file at all. If the handlers/main.yml file is there I don't get a notify event

Comment: Are you letting the playbook completely run to the end? Handlers by default get called at the very end of the play. In case you abort the play or an error occurs in another task after notifying the handler, the handler never would get called (by default). Also, the copy/generate tasks are clearly marked as _changed_ state (yellow) in Ansible output?

Comment: @udondan, ya that works fine in 1.9 but not 2.0 and yes they are marked as yellow in the output

Comment: That's strange. I can't see an issue. But I can confirm handlers work for me in Ansible 2.0.0.2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, because of the wrong file type, your handlers are getting ignored I suppose:

> roles/sensu/handlers/*main.html*

Should be: `roles/sensu/handlers/main.yml`

Secondly, please note, although you have a couple of handlers, the only handler that is notified by the notifiers is: `restart sensu client`. So the other handlers won't get run.

> Handlers are lists of tasks, not really any different from regular
>   tasks, that are referenced by a globally unique name. Handlers are
>   what notifiers notify. If nothing notifies a handler, it will not run.
>   Regardless of how many things notify a handler, it will run only once,
>   after all of the tasks complete in a particular play.

Ref: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: so the html/yml was a test.. and that isn't the cause and i'm just expecting the `restart sensu client` to be run.. this is for v2.0.2 btw.

Comment: @Mike, I see, It seems it is just getting ignored because of it's location or filename. what if you add an include directive for the handlers file? Something like: `- include: sensu/handlers/main.yml`, at the end of your main play file.